# Fresh Fedora 35 - what are these active internet connections doing?

Tags: fedora, netstat

To get to this point I had a Fedora workstation 34 install- iso about a week old - ran update, rebooted, click Install Fedora 35 as it was on offer from gnome Software. Hadn't even opened Firefox yet. Didn't install anything else.

I ran netstat just to see what was happening by default.
There were a couple established connections to Cloudflare addresses which had no additional whois info to go on, ok

and one to an oscp-router.gno (assuming thats Gnome extensions),

But this one really stands out:

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State
tcp 25 0 fedora:58440 proxy14.fedorapro:https CLOSE_WAIT
```

Why did Fedora connect to proxy14.fedorapro ?
I can't find any information about this. fedorapro.com is a parked domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output is truncated, that was a connection to `proxy14.fedoraproject.org`, probably for an automated check for updates.

```
ss -rt
```

would show you the full host name.